# Grunt js entirely non-functional

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt but am failing to get it to do anything very much.

Am using ubuntu 14.04, and have installed npm from the repo, then grunt using `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`.

Running run achieves nothing. I get no error message, nothing happens, the command just returns. Rather confused. Not sure what to try next.

I am trying to run the commands in a fresh check out of reveal.js.

Comment: You mean `npm install -g`?

Comment: This is going to be impossible to debug without much more information. You've basically just said, *"it doesn't work, why?"*

Comment: Yes, I agree, Liam. Not sure what to test next. I would expect something to work, or to fail. Does grunt log anywhere?

Comment: There isn't much to work on here to help you with, have you read through the Getting Started Guide? http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

If you install grunt, you can invoke it with `grunt`. This will run the default task specified in the `Gruntfile.js` or `Gruntfile.coffee` in the very same folder. The default task is registered like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [...]);
```